# Google desktop on Server - indexing takes a long time

Tags: windows-server-2003, remote-desktop, google, indexing

How is your experience of Google desktop on server?

My server is relatively slow (quite slow actually). I have installed Google desktop to speed up the search process. It started indexing a week ago. It quickly started to 6% complete, then slowly and slowly ... 40% over the next 5 days. Now it just started to index again and has reached 6%.

While Google desktop runs quick and awesome on desktop, how is your experience with server? Are there things that I do not know?

I am running it on MS Windows Server 2003.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why on earth would you install Google Desktop on a server? That's got bad idea written all over it. I don't mean that question rhetorically, either. I literally cannot think of a single legitimate reason to install it on a server and I'm curious about why you think your situation dictates its usage.

If the Microsoft-blessed Windows Search 4.0 isn't doing it's job, then you should figure out why. Clearly if you are having problems with both that and Google Desktop, you have a problem with your server. Break out [perfmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490957.aspx) and find your problem, don't try and hide it by trying a different tool.

Comment: I also read Google Desktop does not support Win Server 2003.

Comment: @SavageGarden Even if it did, just because something is supported doesn't mean it's a good idea.

Comment: But I do not know why it is a bad idea?

Comment: @SavageGarden What problem do you think it solves that you're currently facing? The general answer is that it's unnecessary software. Nothing that it does is useful on a server. Installing crap on a server exposes it to more security holes and can cause stability problems. The specific answer depends on what problem you're facing.

Comment: when I search server for a word, it takes hours to complete. The bottle neck which I found is memory (only 2GB on server).

Comment: @SavageGarden Why are you searching for files on the server? Do you have Windows Search 4.0 installed? Is the location that you're searching indexed? 2GB RAM is certainly not a lot, but if the files are indexed and the disk isn't being crushed, it shouldn't take that long. Methinks your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: I installed Windows Search 4.0 after this question and removed Google desktop. The server contains archive which needs to be searched once in a while.